# Populate JSON data to ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-volley

I am trying to display a retrieved data from MySQL database with the help of Volley, and populate it into a `ListView`.
So far as I tried every method I am unable to do it.

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Log.d("TAG", response.toString());

        try {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> authorList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                String username      = obj.getString("username");
                String email         = obj.getString("email");
                String password      = obj.getString("password");

                usernameAll += "UserName: " + username + "\n\n";
                emailAll    += "Email: "    + email + "\n\n";
                passwordAll += "Password: " + password + "\n\n";                      
        }
```

As I have retrieved '*username*', '*email*', and '*password*' I can successfully show it in `TextView` by `myTextView.setText(usernameAll + " " + ..);`. But for now I just want to print/populate 'username' in `Simple ListView`

```
HashMap<String, String> myData = new HashMap<>();
myData.put("justKey", usernameAll);
adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myData);
listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

When I take some `Array` and call that array it works but why `myData` isn't working. Can you please help me understanding the actual problem.
My next step will be to use the `Custom ListView` but now I am eager "*how actually stuff works*"

I will really appreciate if you correct my approach of solving this problem.

Thank You.

**PS:** I am getting this error from Android Studio 2.1.2:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int,
>   int, java.lang.String)'

Comment: What is your listview adapter code? It's easiest to start off with a custom listview honestly, best way to learn it than going generic in this situation, just jump right in. When you say myData isn't working, what do you mean? Is usernameAll coming back as null? Why not make a user object that saves the username, email and password, and store those in a data structure, would be much easier to display them when you get to it in the listview.

Comment: Hello @Steeno! Thank You for the comments. Well I am stuck at it, I don't know what to do. Actually this is my first time to try. My code up to String password = obj.getString("password"); is okay to me. The other you suggest to me. So it would be more helful if you show me how to do it? | The `usernameAll` isn't null, I can display it on _TextView_. But can't in ListView. If you want to suggest me any other code, It will be great. Thank You.

Comment: I am getting this error: `Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, java.lang.String)'` from this statement: `adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, usernameAll);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can't pass hashmap to the array adapter

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

convert it to the list as mentioned in the documentation also

```
//Code Getting Collection of values from HashMap

Collection<String> values = myData.values();

//Creating an ArrayList of values

ArrayList<String> listOfValues = new ArrayList<String>(values);
```

For details check out the link below
http://javaconceptoftheday.com/how-to-convert-hashmap-to-arraylist-in-java/

Comment: Aha! Thank You. Seems like Converting from `HashMap` to `List` for me is a bit hard. | Can you/anyone please help me with a little code snippet that I use in `ArrayAdapter` and I will be able to display all values in `ListView`? Thanks in advance.